# Combine two data tables in R by a condition referring to two columns

Tags: r, join, merge, data.table

I have two data tables that I want to merge/join based on values in two columns that can appear in reverse order in the two data tables. 
Here are two example data tables:

```
library(data.table)
# df1
col1 <- c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd") 
col2 <- c("bb", "zz", "dd", "ff") 
x <- c(130, 29, 122, 85)
dt1 <- data.table(col1, col2, x)

   col1  col2  x
1:   aa   bb 130
2:   bb   zz  29
3:   cc   dd 122
4:   dd   ff  85

# df2
col1 <- c("zz", "bb", "cc", "ff") 
col2 <- c("bb", "aa", "dd", "dd") 
y <- c(34, 567, 56, 101)
dt2 <- data.table(col1, col2, y)

    col1 col2  y
1:   zz   bb  34
2:   bb   aa 567
3:   cc   dd  56
4:   ff   dd 101
```

So the values in col1 and col2 taken together are the same for both data tables, but the distribution is different. E.g. aa is in col1 in dt1, but in col2 in dt2. 
I want to merge/join the data tables based on pairs of col1 and col2, but they might be in reverse order in the other data table. (Note that simply sorting them doesn't work.)

This means that the merge/join etc. must be able to 'see' that the pair aa+bb in dt1 occurs as bb+aa in dt2 and assign the correct value of dt2, i.e. the desired output is either:

```
   col1 col2   x   y
1:   aa   bb 130 567
2:   bb   zz  29  34
3:   cc   dd 122  56
4:   dd   ff  85 101
```

or this (i.e. whether the order of dt1 or dt2 is retained doesn't matter):

```
   col1 col2   x   y
1:   zz   bb  29  34
2:   bb   aa 130 567
3:   cc   dd 122  56
4:   ff   dd  85 101
```

My original data tables have approx. 3 million rows (yes, they're huge), so doing anything by hand is out of the question. 
I've looked around here, but I couldn't find any solution that is applicable to my case. Does anyone know how to do this?

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Comment: `dt2[col1 > col2, c("col1", "col2") := .(col2, col1)]; dt1[dt2, on=.(col1, col2)]` works. Or you could use `:=` to add the column to `dt1` as sirallen suggested.

Comment: @Frank, this works! Thanks so much! Do you maybe want to post that as an answer?

Comment: Np, glad it works :) Feel free to edit your answer with it or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, we have two solutions that work!

Version 1:
Adapted from Frank's comment above:

```
 library(dplyr)
 final <- dt2[col1 > col2, c("col1", "col2") := .(col2, col1)]
 final <- dt1[dt2, on=.(col1, col2)]
 final <- select(final, col1, col2, x, y) # select relevant columns
 final
  col1 col2   x   y
1:   bb   zz  29  34
2:   aa   bb 130 567
3:   cc   dd 122  56
4:   dd   ff  85 101
```

Version2: This is just a tweak of PritamJ's answer that simplifies a few things and makes this solution more applicable for large data tables. Hope it helps other people as well!

```
library(dplyr)
dt1$pairs <- paste(dt1$col1, dt1$col2) # creates new column with col1 and col2 
merged into one
dt2$pairs <- paste(dt2$col1, dt2$col2) # same here
dt2$revpairs <- paste(dt2$col2, dt2$col1) # creates new column with reverse pairs

f1 <- merge(dt1, dt2, by="pairs") # merge by pairs as they are in dt1
f1 <- select(f1, col1.x, col2.x, x, y) # select by name (easier for big dt) 

f2 <- merge(dt1, dt2, by.x = "pairs", by.y = "revpairs") # merge by pairs and reverse pairs
colnames(f2)[ncol(f2)] <- "revpairs" # rename last column because it has the same name as the first, which can cause errors
f2 <- select(f2, col1.x, col2.x, x, y) 


final <- bind_rows(f2, f1) # bind the two together
colnames(final)[1:2] <- c("col1", "col2") # this is not necessary, just for clarity
final
   col1 col2   x   y
1:   aa   bb 130 567
2:   bb   zz  29  34
3:   dd   ff  85 101
4:   cc   dd 122  56
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
dt1[dt2, on=.(col1, col2), y:= y]

dt1[dt2, on=.(col1==col2, col2==col1), y:= i.y]

> dt1
#    col1 col2   x   y
# 1:   aa   bb 130 567
# 2:   bb   zz  29  34
# 3:   cc   dd 122  56
# 4:   dd   ff  85 101
```

Comment: This works well for the example dt, but if I run it on the actual data tables, I get this error when I try to run the second line:  `Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in more than 2^31 rows (internal vecseq reached physical limit). Very likely misspecified join. Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation.` I tried EACHI, but then I get wrong values for y. How can I solve this?

Comment: I also tried allow.cartesian= TRUE, but that just results in the same error.

Comment: I didn't think `==` worked inside `on=`. Why not `=` instead? Also, is there any reason not to use `i.y` in the first line?

Comment: @Frank thanks for the hints. I tried both of these 'fixes', but still get the same error.

Comment: @SandraA. ... do you have duplicate (col1, col2) pairs in your tables?

Comment: @Frank, the first dt for sure has no duplicates. the second one might have 'reverse' duplicates (i.e. a row with "xx" in col1 and "yy" in col2 but also a row with "yy" in col1 and "xx" in col2), but not real duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Didn't able to find any straight answer , so tried the below code. 
Hope it will help

```
require(stringi)
require(data.table)
require(dplyr)
dt1$as <- paste(dt1$col1,dt1$col2)
dt2$as <- paste(dt2$col1,dt2$col2)
dt2$as1 <- stringi::stri_reverse(dt2$as)

f1 <- merge(dt1,dt2,by="as")
f1 <- subset(f1,select=c(2,3,4,7))
f1 <- setnames(f1,c("col1.x","col2.x"),c("Col1","Col2"))
f2 <- merge(dt1,dt2,by.x = "as",by.y = "as1")
f2 <- subset(f2,select=c(2,3,4,7))
f2 <- setnames(f2,c("col1.x","col2.x"),c("Col1","Col2"))
final <- bind_rows(f2,f1)

final
    Col1 Col2   x   y
1:   aa   bb 130 567
2:   bb   zz  29  34
3:   dd   ff  85 101
4:   cc   dd 122  56
```

Comment: Thanks, with a few tweaks this worked! Maybe not the most concise solution but it does the trick! I'll post my modified version as an answer.